# MVC 3 Custom Authorization attribute isDefined always returns true

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, attributes

I have defined a custom Authorization Attribute and it is automaticly applied to all actions in the solution.
In its OnAuthorize method i use the IsDefined method to find if another attribute is defined but it seems that it always returns false.

Edit: the AuthorizeAttr attribute is set in the RegisterGlobalFilters function in Global.asax and the Anon attribute is marked directly above the actions that doesn´t need authorization.

Here is my code:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class Anon : Attribute { }

public class Role : Attribute
{
    public int Id;
    public Role(int id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }
}

public class AuthorizeAttr : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!(filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(Anon), false)) || !(filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(Anon), false)))
        {
            Procurement.User u = MvcApplication.GetCurrentUser(filterContext.HttpContext);
            if (u == null || !u.enabled)
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/Session/Login?msg=You must log in to use this site.&ReturnUrl=" + filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl);
            if (filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(Role), false))
            {
                object[] criterias = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Role), false);
                bool authorized = true;
                for (int x = 0; x < criterias.Length; x++)
                {
                    if (((Role)criterias[x]).Id > u.roleId)
                    {
                        authorized = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (!authorized)
                {
                    ContentResult C = new ContentResult();
                    C.Content = "<h1><b>The resource is unavailable!</b></h1>";
                    filterContext.Result = C;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In boolean algebra the negation of

```
isDefinedOnAction || isDefinedOnController
```

is:

```
!isDefinedOnAction && !isDefinedOnController
```

So you probably want an `&&` condition:

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    var isDefinedOnAction = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(Anon), false);
    var isDefinedOnController = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(Anon), false);
    if (!isDefinedOnAction && !isDefinedOnController)
    {
        ... the Anon attribute is not present neither on an action nor on a controller
        => perform your authorization here
    }
}
```

or if you want `||`:

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    var isDefinedOnAction = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(Anon), false);
    var isDefinedOnController = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(Anon), false);
    if (isDefinedOnAction || isDefinedOnController)
    { 
        ... the attribute is present on either a controller or an action
        => do nothing here
    }
    else
    {
        ... perform your authorization here
    }
}
```

Obviously the first is by far more readable.

Comment: AH!
Ofcource!
Since i negate the result it is checking if it doesnt exist and only one of them not having the attribute lets the code in the if-statement get executed.
Sorry for posting a simple logical problem and thenks for the help!

Comment: @Mats Edvinsson, I have tested the code and it worked fine. What are the values of the `isDefinedOnAction` and `isDefinedOnController` variables before the if condition? Are they both false? Did you decorate a controller or an action with the `[Anon]` attribute?

Comment: Both are false and yes i have defined the [Anon] attribute on both the Index of the HomeController and the Login page which this code redirects to.
It just ends up in an redirection-loop.

Comment: @Mats Edvinsson, I have just tested the scenario you described and it worked perfectly fine for me. Are you sure that it is the `Index` action that is being requested? What are the values of `filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName` and `filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName` when you first enter inside the attribute?

Comment: First it accesses Index which redirects to an action which needs authorization which redirects to the login-page(which has the [Anon] attribute) but the login-page keeps redirecting to itself.
that was the case a moment ago, now it tries to access Index and just hangs for some reason.

Comment: @Mats Edvinsson, in your implementation of the attribute, if the user is not authorized **you are not redirecting**. You are simply returning a `ContentResult`. By the way you are better of overriding the `AuthorizeCore` and `HandleUnautheroizedResult` methods instead of `OnAuthorization`.

Comment: Yes, that is if there is a [Role] attribute on the current action.
I dont have any [Role] attributes placed at all yet.

Comment: Can you send me a stripped down version of a sample project which illustrates this problem? You could remove all irrelevant parts of the actual authorization. Just a brand new application with 2 controllers and a sample authorize attribute.

Comment: Made a stripped down project now, however, everything seems to work there.
In other words there is probably something minor in the main project that differs which i should be able to fix on my own so ill go ahead and try.
Ill mark your answer as the solution.
Thanks for the help!